# Invalid Identifer when trying to create a table in LiveSQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Just starting out with SQL.

However, I keep getting invalid identifier error.

```
CREATE TABLE HospitalPatinets ( 
PatientNo       Varchar2(4), 
ForeName        Varchar2(20), 
LastName        Varchar2(20), 
AddressLine1    Varchar2(20), 
AddressLine2    Varchar2(20), 
BudgetAlloc     Number, 
DoB             DATE, 
Surgery         Char(3), 
)
```

That is the code I am entering

Comment: is it because of the comma in `Surgery         Char(3),`?

Comment: PatientNo  Varchar2(4)? Be prepared to run out of PatientNo's... (Or switch to integer,  asap.)